# What does google closure's typedef actually do?

Tags: javascript, google-closure, jsdoc

I understand what it is for - I can see the benefits of being able to define an alias for a complex type and use that in the documentation. So you can define a type something like...

```
/** @typedef {{x:number, y:number}} */
example.Point;
```

...and then use it to document a function, something like...

```
/**
 * @param {example.Point} point
 * @return {example.Point}
 */
example.functionThatTakesAPointAndReturnsAPoint(point) {
....
}
```

But the thing I'm not sure about is, if it's only used for documentation and the compiler's static type checking, then why does the typedef need that line of JavaScript? Couldn't the alias just be defined entirely within the documentation comment block?  And, if you served the code directly (without compiling it), what would the JavaScript interpreter do with that line of code after the typedef comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is built on top of Rhino and just enhances the available syntax. I assume it was easier to take the alias from a no-op property access because it matches the standard pattern.

Comment: Thanks - I think that's the kind of info I was looking for.  So that line of JavaScript after the typedef does nothing...and it was implemented that way basically for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can set a type declaration directly in your method doc:

```
/**
 * @param {{x:number, y:number}} pointLike
 */
var myFn = function(pointLike) {
 return pointLike.x + ':' + pointLike.y;
}

alert(myFn({x:34, y:20}))
alert(myFn({x:34, y:'20'})) // will trigger compile time type warning
```

Benefits of using a `@typedef` for object types that you use in several places are more in usability/clarity.

For example: maybe you'll get a 'Point.z' attr sometime soon. Using typedef you'd only have to update the typedef declaration and not each inline type declaration in your whole codebase.

See also [Using Google Closure's @typedef tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949492/using-google-closures-typedef-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Its not only for documentation. It gives you also warning when you compile your script using the closure compiler.

> The Closure Compiler can use data type information about JavaScript
>   variables to provide enhanced optimization and warnings. JavaScript,
>   however, has no way to declare types.

Comment: Thanks - I get that bit...I was just a little confused as to why it needed that line of JavaScript code to do that. Why, for example, the typedef couldn't just be something like /** @typedef {{x:number, y:number}} example.Point */.

I'm fairly new to JavaScript so I just wanted to make sure there wasn't something going on there that I'm not understanding properly.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if the whole typedef was defined in a comment. Defining part of it as code has some unintended consequences. See this [blog post](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2017/01/common-pitfalls-when-using-typedefs-in.html).

The reason the typedef name is defined in the actual code is the way the parsing and typechecking works in Closure Compiler. The parser needs to attach each jsdoc comment to an AST node, otherwise the comment is silently ignored. So, the name of the typedef is defined as code, the jsdoc is attached to it, and later the typechecker picks up the type definition.